# Getting gstreamer to work on Windows 7 with python

Tags: python, windows-7, gstreamer

I'm trying to get gstreamer working with python 2.7 on a windows 7 machine and having some troubles.

I have installed both the WinBuilds Runtime and SDK several times, but the system still doesn't recognize that I have it.

(it gives me the module not found error)

I got the downloads from here
http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/downloads/list

I get the error right at the statment
    import gst

I can import pygst fine, but when i try to import gst, I get the

```
File "play.py", line 15 in <module>
  import gst
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\Gstreamer\v0.10.6\lib\site-packages\gst-0.10\gst\__init__.py", line 193, in <module>
from _gst import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have yet to find any clear instructions on how to install this on windows, I've tried adding several paths to my PATH system variable in attempts to get it working, currently in my PATH variable I have

C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStream\bin;

C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStreamer\v0.10.6\sdk\bindings\python\v2.6\lib

Anyone currently developing with gstreamer and windows 7? How did you get it to work?

Thanks.

Comment: __Please__ paste the exact error message (and the line of code it happens on. And what version specifically do you have installed? What about gst-python or whatever?

Comment: I answered a question about the same problem a while ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907473/cannot-import-gst-in-python

Comment: On importing gst I am getting the error that the module does not exist. What do I do?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to use GStreamer 1.0 is to download the latest version from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/

引用：from:　[gstreamer python bindings for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278953/gstreamer-python-bindings-for-windows)