# Webcam capture in Python 3.4 on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, win64, webcam-capture

I have seen different modules like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) and [Videocapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) for taking fast shots from the computer webcam, but these are only for Python 2. I thought I would make one work with Pygame, but I got many errors. I found different pages including pygame's website that said it only works with Linux.

Are there any modules for Python 3.4 for Windows that can quickly take shots from the webcam?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can apparently be installed on Windows with Python 3, according to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26491054/1510289).

After OpenCV, my 2nd recommendation is to use GStreamer, and this is apparently possible on your specific platform according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21082448/1510289).

Comment: I tried instructions listed in both of these and couldn't get either to work. i am using Python 3.4. GStreamer's instructions you linked to are for Python 3.3.