# Install python-gobject and python-gtk with miniconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, miniconda

I've recently switched to miniconda (from just using pip), my system is the following:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- miniconda2 python 2.7.5

However, I'm completely confused how to install two particular libraries and cannot find any information online. Usually, I would install these via

`~ sudo apt-get install python-gobject
~ sudo apt-get insatll python-gtk2`

But this obviously installs them for the system python and not the miniconda version. I tried

`~ conda install gobject`

and was informed that

```
Error:  Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - gobject

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

```
anaconda search -t conda gobject
```

```

I searches and found a multitude of what I think are people repo's with names including gobject, but how can I determine which, if any, are the same as the module which is installed with `python-gobject`? I tried a few, but ended up with hundreds of conflicts.

What I would really like to do is just install the ubuntu version, but for miniconda. Any help is much appreciated and I'm sorry this is quite a basic question: I really don't understand the python ecosystem sometimes.

Comment: I managed to download `pygobject3` from the pkgw and lightsource2 channels, but I am getting the following error when trying to import `gi` in anaconda python `ImportError: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I've given up with miniconda, people rave about it but all I get is confusion.

Comment: I think you could use the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40303128/2377431