# Cannot import `gi`in Python to satisfactorily execute `ibus-setup`

Tags: python, import, module

My issue is similar to what was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526026/how-to-install-gi-module-for-anaconda-python3) 3 years ago, but in my case on Arch Linux 5.3.7.  Not certain this is the right place to ask though.

Motivation: I want to run `ibus-setup` to correct what I believe is the key binding CTRL-SHIFT-E being hijacked by my GTK apps (Firefox + LibreOffice) to open an annoying emoji-picker window. Concretely I want to suppress what I think might be a default GTK key binding.

I thought I might try that with `ibus-setup`.

```
$ ibus-setup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    from gi import require_version as gi_require_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

I found that "gi" is part of  package `extra/python-gobject` which I installed, along with `extra/python2-gobject` and `extra/python-gobject2` for good measure.

I ran `$ ibus-setup` again both in my global Python 3.7.4 env and in a Python 2.7.16 (pyenv) virtual environment, although the Python RTE outside the process(es) launched by `ibus-setup` should not matter. Same error.

`/usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py` is python2 code and I could not see anything blatantly wrong with how `gi` is invoked.

I even tried the small python snippet [here](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#arch-getting-started) to check that `gi` is correctly imported when called from python on my box, both in Python 3.7 and 2.7.  Worked well, which means that `gi`can be correctly imported from `python` console.

I'm stumped. Any pointer anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lied in either:

1. removing your virtual environment be it Conda, Pyenv, or otherwise, although
   that hack does not represent a viable solution, if you (as I)
   rely on virtual environments for your work. This is because virtual
   environments introduce new default paths for the default Python to
   execute.
2. or, provided your `PYTHON` environment variable is **not** set, modifying the `/usr/bin/ibus-setup` shell script so the last line
   reads:
   `exec "${PYTHON:-/usr/bin/python3}" /usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py "$@"`
3. or specifying the `PYTHON` environment variable when launching `ibus-setup` from terminal:

   `> PYTHON=/usr/bin/python ibus-setup`

This 3rd approach is probably the most flexible way of dealing with the OP's issue.  Doing so circumvents the fact that the new default path for Python 3.x in my case, with `pyenv`, is `$HOME/.pyenv/shims/python`. Note that the redefined path is restricted to the spawned shell if any.  Also in my case `/usr/bin/python` points to `/usr/bin/python3` by means of a symbolic link.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your system has python2 installed, a possible solution is perhaps `alias python=python2` in your shell, then try `ibus-setup` again.

I encountered the same issue today on Ubuntu 18.04. I was in a conda environment (py3.6). After deactivating the environment, it works. Using `which python` and `python --version`, I believe it invoked python2.7 from `usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

whereis ibus-setup

example: vim /usr/bin/ibus-setup

change   exec **python3** /usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py $@  ===>> exec **python2**/usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py $@