# Mono Playback of Mp3s in Python OR C++

Tags: c++, python, audio, mp3

Im coding a [music player](https://github.com/fabiomdiniz/Gokya-2-The-Super-Gokya/) in python using pyqt and I wanted it to feature mono playback of mp3 files.

I've accomplished that using pygame, as its mixer has a specific parameter `channels` that I can set to `1` to get mono playback.

However, pygame [mp3 support is limited](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html), so I'm searching for a library that will be able to handle mp3 files AND mono playback.

Currently, I'm using pyaudiere for playback and on its [site](http://pyaudiere.org/) there's an example of processing the song before playing it, so maybe I could do that to turn the song to mono, but I really have no idea how to accomplish that.

I'd like help on how to code this feature using pyaudiere or any other library that can handle mp3 files.

**EDIT**

I would also accept a solution in C++, as I can always build a python wrapper using Boost::python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you want really good Windows support I suspect you might need or find it easier to use a different API for Windows... check these links:

- http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/ (cross-platform)
- http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html (cross-platform)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx (Windows-specific)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (Windows-specific)

EDIT - most probably the solution (so far the comments are pretty positive):

Another option is http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html (beware: commercial) - it does all you asked for, is free for use in non-commercial applications and there is a python wrapper (called pybass)...

Comment: Pyaudio will only manipulate streams of data (that id have to read with another library like pymedia), is it possible to add stuff like seeking to it in a simple way? I still have to check if ffmpeg can be used and the other 2 solutions are not suited (one in C# and the other is too low-level)

Comment: @FabioDiniz link 3 was just to show how the API from link 4 can be used... I added another option which does all you asked for but this one is commercial - not sure that is ok for you

Comment: OH WOW. Bass is incredible, it really does all I've asked, at home I'll conduct more tests but everything is working the way I wanted so far.

Comment: @FabioDiniz glad to read that... one addition: the license states that it is free for use in non-commercial software :-)

Comment: Yeah, and as im coding a non-commercial application it fits perfectly. Im also using a python wrapper called pybass, and it is really incredible. I can even turn to mono WITHOUT restarting the stream, which is really impressive for such a high level library

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Python Audio Tools](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/index.html)?  It has the ability to load an MP3 and play it using the `Player` class.  The `Player` class initializer accepts an [`AudioOutput`](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/programming/audiotools_player.html) object, which lets you specify the number of playback channels.

The project seems well supported with the last [git commit](https://github.com/tuffy/python-audio-tools) on October 30th of 2011 (just under two weeks prior to your posting).  It's also been around for a while, so it doesn't appear to be a fly-by-night library.

Comment: After a bit of reasearch i havent found a way (or binaries) to get it working on Windows, and i need it to be windows-compatible

Answer (score 1):

[Gstreamer's Python bindings](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/index.html).

Here's a very simple music player:

```
import gobject
import gst
pipeline = gst.parse_launch('filesrc location="stereo.mp3" ! mad ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1 ! autoaudiosink')
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

gobject.threads_init()
gobject.MainLoop().run()
```

I really suggest you look into Gstreamer as it has become a de-facto multimedia solution for most of the open source platforms and supports a wide variety of audio files. Sample apps using it: Rhythmbox, Banshee, Totem, etc...

Comment: Id really like to use gstreamer, but i have this issue posted on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907473/cannot-import-gst-in-python), and the solution posted does not work for me

Comment: Oh yes, the joys of Windows and its lack of package management :S

Comment: =( Im downgrading to python 2.6 to see if i get gst work, but id really prefer a solution in which i could use python 2.7

Comment: I got it to work but the windows support is horrible (im using Ossbuild), theres a lag to play/pause (and a hiccup) and lag to change the volume, but (sadly) the mono/stereo feature works quite well

Comment: @FabioDiniz How are you sending the play/pause messages?

Comment: by using set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING) and set_state(gst.STATE_PAUSE). It seems a problem similar to [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/PLAY-gt-PAUSE-gt-PLAY-hickup-td1592437.html). Maybe ossbuild is not ready yet, I`ve tried Banshee for windows and it is as sluggish as my application.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not even close to a complete answer, to turn a multichanneled audio wav file into a mono one, you simply get the average of all the channels. 
In the case of stereo you would have:

`mono[i]=(left[i]+right[i])/2`

for each sample `i`.

Hope it helps!