# Read MP3 in Python 3

Tags: python, audio, python-3.x, mp3

What I want to do is simply

```
mp3 = read_mp3(mp3_filename)
audio_left = mp3.audio_channels[0]
```

where audio_left will contain raw PCM audio data.

I was looking at [Play a Sound with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python), but most of the suggested modules are not ported to Python 3 yet. If possible I'd like to avoid having to install a fully-fledged game dev library.

I'm a complete Python beginner, so I'd like to start off using Python 3.

Comment: Do you want left channel only for some particular reason, or do you just want the audio in general

Comment: @Daenyth, I just want a monophonic signal, so if I can have mp3.audio.toMono(), even better :)

Comment: You might want to see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064784/mono-playback-of-mp3s-in-python-or-c

Comment: I know that GStreamer can play back mp3 and is widely used. A Python binding for GStreamer including Python 3 therefore has some chances. I found [gst-python](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html). Sorry, I can not make a real answer out of it, because I lack the knowledge of this module, but this might be just a hint for someone else wanting to continue.

Comment: Try -  librosa, a popular package for music and audio analysis. Simple usage example is available in my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using an mpg123 subprocess to convert the mp3 to wav, and then I use scipy.io.wavfile.read to read the wav file.

Answer (score 18):

To make it easier I'd convert with some tools mp3 to wav, either:

```
$ ffmpeg -i foo.mp3 -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -f wav foo.wav
or
$ mpg123 -w foo.wav foo.mp3
```

Then read the WAV with [one of the python WAV libraries](https://github.com/mgeier/python-audio/tree/master/audio-files). I'd recommend [**PySoundFile**](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-pysoundfile.ipynb) because it works with most generated WAV correctly and installed without issue (as opposed to `scikits.audiolab`).

Note: Even though `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` gave me a "WavFileWarning: Unfamiliar format bytes" warning, it also loaded the file properly.

Answer (score 18):

You could use librosa:

```
import librosa
y, sr = librosa.load('your_file.mp3')
```

Further information: https://github.com/librosa/librosa

Comment: Your command did not work for me using librosa 0.6.3. Had to do `y, sr = librosa.load('your_file.mp3', sr=44100)`

Comment: From librosa docs: By default, librosa will resample the signal to 22050Hz. meaning `sr` parameter is optional.

Comment: Please note, that librosa does not support in-buffer reading for mp3 files according to bug in libsndfile mentioned in librosa's dependency SoundFile https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile/issues/250#issuecomment-572440286

Answer (score 10):

Can be done with pydub:

```
import array
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import get_array_type

sound = AudioSegment.from_file(file=path_to_file)
left = sound.split_to_mono()[0]

bit_depth = left.sample_width * 8
array_type = get_array_type(bit_depth)

numeric_array = array.array(array_type, left._data)
```

Answer (score 7):

I am considering using FFmpeg as a subprocess. There is a Python wrapper called pyffmpeg, but I had difficulty installing it on my system (OS X 10.7.3).

You may also want to look at the code here for calling FFmpeg as a subprocess from Python: https://github.com/albertz/learn-midi/blob/master/decode.py

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best to do this and that is also compatible with Python 3.x is:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mplayer.py/

I highly recommend that you look at Darwin M. Bautista's [git](https://github.com/baudm/mplayer.py) or [google code](https://code.google.com/p/python-mplayer/):

And here is an example from (as provided by him):

```
from mplayer import Player, CmdPrefix

# Set default prefix for all Player instances
Player.cmd_prefix = CmdPrefix.PAUSING_KEEP

# Since autospawn is True by default, no need to call player.spawn() manually
player = Player()

# Play a file
player.loadfile('mp3_filename')

# Pause playback
player.pause()

# Get title from metadata
metadata = player.metadata or {}
print metadata.get('Title', '')

# Print the filename
print player.filename

# Seek +5 seconds
player.time_pos += 5

# Set to fullscreen
player.fullscreen = True

# Terminate MPlayer
player.quit()
```

**List of supported audio codecs:**

- MPEG layer 1, 2, and 3 (MP3) audio
- AC3/A52, E-AC3, DTS (Dolby Digital) audio (software or SP/DIF)
- AAC (MPEG-4 audio)
- WMA (DivX Audio) v1, v2
- WMA 9 (WMAv3), Voxware audio, ACELP.net etc (using x86 DLLs)
- RealAudio: COOK, SIPRO, ATRAC3 (using Real libraries)
- RealAudio: DNET and older codecs
- QuickTime: Qclp, Q-Design QDMC/QDM2, MACE 3/6 (using QT libraries), ALAC
- Ogg Vorbis audio
- VIVO audio (g723, Vivo Siren) (using x86 DLL)
- alaw/ulaw, (ms)gsm, pcm, *adpcm and other simple old audio formats

Comment: Can you give a code example that addresses the problem in the question? That is, code that extracts PCM data from an input file ready for further analysis?

Comment: Actually, this looks like it doesn't satisfy the "no subprocess invocation" requirement. It just wraps an MPlayer process, which it looks for as `mplayer`, and I suspect that will be quite fragile on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Code for playing songs in Python

```
pip3 install python-vlc
```

Download the python VLC package

Code - `import vlc`

```
#plays the song for 10 seconds

import vlc
import time

song = 'zik.mp3'

playSong = vlc.MediaPlayer(song)
playSong.play()
time.sleep(10)
playSong.stop()
```

or

pip3 install playsound

```
import playsound

song = 'path_to_the_.mp3_file'

playsound.playsound(song)
```

That's  it!