# GStreamer with Python 2.7 cannot import gst

Tags: python, pygtk, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am having the same issue as:
[Cannot Import GST in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907473/cannot-import-gst-in-python)
However, its solution does not work for me.

I'm using Win7 64bit with Python 2.7, GStreamer 0.10.7, and PyGTK 2.24.  The exact error I receive is:

```
>>>import gst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gst-0.10\gst\__init__.py", line 87, in <mo
dule>
    from _gst import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst
```